# How to use a Linked-List implementation with this Hash Function to avoid collisions?

Tags: c#, hash, linked-list, collision

So for my assignment in my class this week, I have to demonstrate a hash function that stores data into a data structure and use a linked list implementation to avoid collisions.  Given the source code from my professor, he stated that the code was correct but to change the array solution to a linked list. I'm not sure what he meant by that but here is the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Hashing
{
class hashFunction
{
    public hashFunction() { }


    public int HashFunc(String s, String[] arr)
    {
        int total = 0;
        char[] cname = s.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < cname.Length; i++)
            total += 37 * total + (int)cname[i];
        total = total % arr.Length;
        if (total < 0)
            total += arr.Length;
        return (int)total;
    }

    public int Collision(int oldHashKey, String[] arr)
    {
        int newHashKey = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            newHashKey = 2 * oldHashKey - 1;
            if (arr[newHashKey] == null)
                break;
        }
        return (int)newHashKey;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] names = new String[10007];
        String[] Animals = new String[] { "Lions", "Tigers", "Bears", "Aligators", "Snakes", "Eagles" };
        storeMessage(names, Animals);
    }

        public static void storeMessage(String[] arrMessage, String[] arrAnimal)
    {
        hashFunction newHashKey = new hashFunction();
        int[] arrayKeys = new int[arrAnimal.Length];
        String nm; int hashVal;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            nm = arrAnimal[i];
            hashVal = newHashKey.HashFunc(nm, arrMessage);
            while (arrMessage[hashVal] != null)
                hashVal = newHashKey.Collision(hashVal, arrMessage);
            arrMessage[hashVal] = nm;
            arrayKeys[i] = hashVal;
        }
    }
}

}
```

It is somewhere with the method for the Collisions that it has to be linked list according to his instruction but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [LinkedList](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linkedlist).

> LinkedList allows fast inserts and removes. It implements a linked
>   list. Each object is separately allocated. Certain operations do not
>   require the whole collection to be copied. In many common cases
>   LinkedList hinders performance.

An example for implementing this in the Collisions:

```
public int Collision(int oldHashKey, LinkedList<string> arr)
{
    int newHashKey = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
    {
        newHashKey = 2 * oldHashKey - 1;
        if (arr[newHashKey] == null)
            break;
    }
    return (int)newHashKey;
}
```

Notice that nothing much really changed. It's just that a LinkedList behaves like a List because it implements ICollection and IEnumerable. It's more convenient than a plain old array because you can just call the method Add and Remove if needed.

Comment: But doesn't this affect the rest of the code in some way?

Comment: You have to refactor all your String[] arr to LinkedList<string> arr. What I showed you is just an example of implementing LinkedList.